# Request to get default ical calendar

Tags: icloud, icalendar, caldav

To get calendar ical calendar list my request is :

```
<d:propfind xmlns:d='DAV:' xmlns:cs='{0}' xmlns:c='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
<d:prop>
<d:resourcetype />
<d:displayname />
<cs:getctag />
<c:supported-calendar-component-set />
<d:current-user-privilege-set/>
<d:calendar-access />
<c:schedule-default-calendar-URL />
</d:prop>
</d:propfind>
```

In Icloud we have option to set default calendar
login to icloud.com -> calendar -> settings -> prefereces -> default

Please tell me which caldav request will return response of this property value in my code.

Comment: Your request looks OK, appart from the cs namespace definition (xmlns:cs='{0}'). You should get back a value for the schedule-default-calendar-URL property, at least on the calendar inbox. What response do you get back ?

Comment: I get the value of calendar that is in the top in my icloud account. I am not getting the value of calendar set in Preferences.

Comment: What is the url that you use to make that PROPFIND request